# how to pass table name as parameter to sql table valued function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I want to pass the table name as a parameter to table_valued function in MS SQL Server

```
CREATE FUNCTION maxid
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @tblname sysname, 
    @feild nvarchar(max),
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here

    select ISNULL(max(@feild),0)+1 from @tblname
)
```

Comment: You **can't**. Variables cannot be used to replace literals, and functions cannot contain dynamic SQL. Also, as an FYI, the datatype for object names is `sysname` (which is a sysnonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`). You certainly need 2GB (1 billion characters) for an object's name.

Comment: is it possible with the store procedure?

Comment: Yes, however, the fact that you want to do this suggest an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). SQL isn't like an programming language. You don't create objects that are multipurpose.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use dynamic SQL in table valued or any other TSQL function. However, the code you provide seems to be used to obtain the next value of some identifier or counter field. The way you want to do it is highly deprecated and leads to concurrency problems. 
Indeed, SQL Server can do it using at least two standard methods:

- using a [sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers)
- creating an [identity column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property)

Comment: This makes a lot of assumptions about the OP's goal here. You might be right, but we don't really have enough to know that this is the actual problem they are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

**I have done it but with store procedure**

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[get_maxid]
@tblname nvarchar(max),
@col nvarchar(max)
as
Begin
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql='select ISNULL(MAX('+@col+'),0)+1 as id from '+ QUOTENAME( @tblname)
execute sp_executesql @sql
End
```

**Now Execute Store Procedure**

```
exec get_maxid @col='col_name',@tblname='tbl_name'
```